# How to implement facebook App Link Host

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate facebook SDK to my android app. After reading the fb doc and samples, I can let the user login with fb account, post status update with my app's shared link. I see the fb support deep link. I really want to use this feature, but I am stuck here, I read the Open Graph doc, can not find android app samples. My app is mobile only, so I plan to use fb's App Links Host service.

Here is my question: 
How can I implement App Link Host API through FacebookDialog or WebDialog when fallback.
I can make request to read the app link data follow the document. But how to produce my own app link meatadata and link to my app's each shared post?

I will continue to do this work on my own and I really hope someone can share this here. Tons of thanks!

Comment: You're not alone. I'm having the same trouble on iOS. Not enough code samples to understand how it works. Let's hope Facebook and App Links update their documentation soon!

Comment: Actually, I suspend this task these days because the schedule changes. But I think I made a little progress. Maybe FacebookDialog or WebDialog can only post the original threads, then we can retrive the posts in fb sdk callback, after we get the post id or something like that, we can use app link edge described in the doc to bind App-link-object to the specified post. Also app access token will be required before we do this. This is just my understanding for now, if I am done with this when I continue, I'll write the abc here. Hope you are doing well!

Comment: @JohnnyWatt Have you achieved any progress with Android Facebook App Link?